# Is winning an adjective

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> The 72-year-old former Booker Prize-**winning** British-Indian novelist has famously also won the Booker of Bookers prize for Midnight’s Children during the anniversary celebrations of the prestigious literary award.

[***Link***](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/news/international/salman-rushdies-quichotte-on-booker-prize-2019-shortlist/article29323660.ece/amp/)

I think **winning** is incorrectly used because it is not a noun, instead **winner** should be used

Comment: No, it's fine as it is. Which is just a natural adjective, same as *She has a winning smile, I'm on a winning streak.* Except in your *specific* context, it's the kind of winning that won him a *Booker Prize*.

Comment: Also the same as in *showing [jaw-dropping stupidity*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22jaw-dropping+stupidity%22), which is a well-worn expression.

Comment: Man-eating tiger, not man-eater tiger.

Comment: Low-hanging fruit, high-flying plane, foul-smelling trousers.